# Caching Response with Dart ServiceStack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, servicestack

I am using the ServiceStack client for Dart in order to perform requests to my API, but I am not able to find a way to cache the response with the client's SDK, has someone found a way to do it? As there is no example on the documentation, only for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in caching in the [ServiceStack's Dart JsonServiceClient](https://docs.servicestack.net/dart-add-servicestack-reference#example-usage).

You would need to maintain your own cache in a local dictionary, ServiceStack's generated Dart DTOs are [JsonCodec compatible](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-dart#jsoncodec-compatible):

```
var dto = new MyDto(name:"foo");
String jsonString = json.encode(dto);
```

So you can use the serialized JSON of the Request DTO as the key to store against the returned Response DTO.

Comment: Ok. I will do it then :(. Thank you for your help :)